# Unable to insert data using hibernate one to one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have two tables:

```
ptUSER(userID, name)
ptProteinData(userID, total, goal)
```

I tried to implement this using `Hibernate` one to one relationship.

The implementation of those 2 tables are the following:

Implementation of `ptUser table (User.java)`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ptuser")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    int userID;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
    String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ptuser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    ProteinData proteinData;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Implementation of `ptProteinData table (ProteinData.java)`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ptproteindata")
public class ProteinData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "ptuser"))
    int userID;
    int total;
    int goal;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    User user;

    //getter & setter
}
```

`DAO` layer implementation is like the following:

```
public class UserDAO {

    public void addUserWithProteinData(String name, int goal, int total) {

        Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);

        ProteinData proteinData = new ProteinData();
        proteinData.setGoal(goal);
        proteinData.setTotal(total);

        user.setProteinData(proteinData);
        proteinData.setUser(user);

        session.saveOrUpdate(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

I tried to insert data using the following code:

```
UserDAO uDAO = new UserDAO();
uDAO.addUserWithProteinData("abc", 100, 10);
```

But I am unable to insert data using the above codes. Can you tell me where I am doing mistake. When I tried to execute this I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mydomain.UserDAO.addUserWithProteinData(UserDAO.java:43)
    at mydomain.UserDAO.main(UserDAO.java:65)
```

Comment: use @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USERID") User user;                      and               remove @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ptuser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    ProteinData proteinData;

Answer (score 0):

Add the first line to your code, because you need to save `proteinData` first and then set in `user` object. Finally, you can save `user`.

```
session.saveOrUpdate(proteinData); // you need to save 'proteinData' first

user.setProteinData(proteinData);
proteinData.setUser(user);
session.saveOrUpdate(user);
```

Also amend these

// On User Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ptuser")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userID")
    int userID;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
    String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ptuser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    ProteinData proteinData;

}
```

// On ProteinData

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ptproteindata")
public class ProteinData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters =  @Parameter(name = "property", value = "ptuser"))
    int userID;
    int total;
    int goal;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="ProteinData")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    User user;

}
```

Comment: I tried that but still same problem with same error.

Comment: Can you debug and see in which line exactly, you are getting the exception? I mean in 'addUserWithProteinData'.

Comment: after debugging i see, "Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();" creates problem. If i delete the relationship then everything is working fine (insert is working fine seperately). but if i include the relationship, then i am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add 
(optional=false)
 @JoinColumn(name="userID", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)

What is the primary key of the second table ProteinData